# Windows C++ __imp reference error when building

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, cygwin, mingw

Environment:

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Eclipse Luna
- cygwin
- MinGW

I am building a C++ program that queries against Active Directory using LDAP (similar to this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). I have the following code sample from the program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include<winldap.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string ldapServerUrl = "192.168.10.29";
    int ldapServerPort = 389;

    LDAP* ldapSession = ldap_init(&ldapServerUrl[0], ldapServerPort);

    return 0;

}
```

When I try to build this sample with the mingw toolchain in Eclipse, the build fails and the line with `ldap_init()` is underlined in red. When I hover the mouse over the error,  it says "Undefined reference to `_imp__ldap_initA()`." When I try it with the cygwin toolchain, it yields a similar error (with slightly different underscore arrangement).

When I try to compile via cmd (`cd` to directory then `g++ main.cpp`, cygwin is in PATH), I get this error:

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/SomeUser/AppData/Local/Temp/ccZczWy3.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x68):
undefined reference to `__imp_ldap_init'
/cygdrive/c/Users/SomeUser/AppData/Local/Temp/ccZczWy3.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x68):
relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp_ldap_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've read some about the `__imp_` prefix being related to linking (this stuff is a bit over my head, normally I'm an Android developer). One term I came across was `declspec`. I took a look at `winldap.h` and it has the following (relevant?) code:

```
#ifndef WINLDAPAPI
#define WINLDAPAPI DECLSPEC_IMPORT
#endif
```

But from there, I have no idea where to go. How do I get this to compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that I did not have the [Windows SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/hardware/hh852363) installed. The first thing I had to do was download and install it.

Then, in Eclipse, I had to make some changes to the project configuration.

First, I had to add the Windows SDK to the paths and symbols include directories (Right click project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> GNU C++ -> Add...). In my case, the directory I had to add was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64`.

Next, I had to add the Windows LDAP library to the Cygwin C++ Linker Library Configuration (Right-click project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Cygwin C++ Linker -> Libraries). Under "Libraries (-l)," add Wldap32.Lib ***(case sensitive!)***.

Now it builds and runs!